# How to enable tmux scrolling?

Tags: tmux

Using https://github.com/samoshkin/tmux-config the master key is `CTRL-a`. The documentation suggests:

```
There is a root keybinding to enter Copy mode: M-Up. Once in copy mode, you have several scroll controls:

    scroll by line: M-Up, M-down
    scroll by half screen: M-PageUp, M-PageDown
    scroll by whole screen: PageUp, PageDown
    scroll by mouse wheel, scroll step is changed from 5 lines to 2
```

but I can't get it to work when pressing `CTRL-A + M-Page*`

Comment: From the copied passage, I would expect to press CTRL+A, **M-Up**, M-PageUp.

Comment: I also expected that - but this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 5):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and then `[`

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

In the top right corner you'll see the line number where your cursor is located.

Now you can scroll up and down. When you finish your scrolling and want to come back to normal operation simply press `q`.

Comment: But I am on a German keyboard -  `[` is only available via `ALT-5` which then no longer seems to work.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I modified my answer to give you an alternative key combination.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also does not work as Page Up is represented as `FN-PgUp`